# Redo/undo option for an action in swing

Tags: java, swing

I am doing barchart demo in that I want the functionality of  doing redo/undo for an event or an action.Can anybody provide me some code snippets which will be greatly appreciated.When i click undo the previous barchart has to be displayed and the vice versa for redo action.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Swing provides Undo and Redo functionality through [javax.swing.undo package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html).

check this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/UndoExample7.htm)

and this [example of Roseindia](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/undoredo.html)

Comment: Thanks for ur updates.But all these will be useful for edittext only rite.I want undo/redo for events what we are doin.

Comment: For example like Back,Forward button in our browser.

Answer (score 0):

One generally implements Undo/Redo by implementing a Command Pattern.  For example, see [Wikiedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) or [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/CommandPattern2inJava.htm) or Google it yourself.  Your application usually stores the previously executed Commands, either just the last one (one one level of undo) or using a Stack (for multiple levels)